# Why my simple code doesn't store the variable in global environment

Tags: r

I have a strange issue that the value of the function is supposed to be stored in the global environment. instead, it returns an error for a line that shouldn't be executed!

```
DEV.OneCancerStrings <- function(Number){
  if(!exists("Number")){
    if(!exists("study_number")){
      study_number <<- 1
      specified_number <- study_number   
    }else if(exists("study_number")){   
      study_number <<- study_number + 1   
      specified_number <- study_number   
    } 
  }else if(exists("Number")){ 
    specified_number <- Number 
  }
}
```

If I execute it without any argument I see the following error:

```
DEV.OneCancerStrings()
Error in DEV.OneCancerStrings() : 
  argument "Number" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: That's the beginning of a larger function but if there is no argument, nothing is stored in the global environment.

Comment: Be aware that this is generally seen as a very bad idea. Rather than modify global state, *return* the new counter and study number. If you need to have an object that maintains a mutable state, encapsulate the functionality in a class.

Comment: From a software engineering point of view `<<- ` is a blemish on R and should seldom if ever be used. Why not use functional inputs and outputs rather than implicit inputs and outputs through side effects?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I need to use 'missing' for the evaluation of function arguments!